# For some reason my window that im creating wont launch

Tags: java, methods

My code is messy so you might not be able to follow it, but I am trying to make a YouTube to MP3 converter.

It opens up a `JPanel` for the user to type in the YouTube URL. When I try to get the text from the `JTextField`, I had to make my method return a value so i can use the value in my other class, and I think that is causing my code not to work.

If someone could help me out, that would be great. I am really new to Java coding and I'm not sure why I chose such a complicated program, but I almost have it done. This is the last part then the cosmetics and cleaning up the code starts :)

**My code:**

```
public class Bank_Statement extends JFrame {

    // width & height of window
    private static final int WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 500;

    public static final Keys text = null;

    final ActionListener convertButtonHandler = null;

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    static String M1;

    public static String Bank_Statement1() {
        //create/set labels
        JButton skinny = new JButton("Convert");
        skinny.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.add(skinny);

        JButton skinny2 = new JButton("Paste");
        JPanel buttonPane2 = new JPanel();
        buttonPane2.add(skinny2);

        JTextField text;
        text = new JTextField("                                                    ");
        JPanel textPane = new JPanel();
        textPane.add(text);

        JTextField text2 = new JTextField("----------------------------------------WAIT LIST----------------------------------------");
        JPanel textPane2 = new JPanel();
        textPane2.add(text2);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Youtube Converter");
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.add(textPane, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(buttonPane2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(textPane2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        return text.getText();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bank_Statement recObject = new Bank_Statement();
    }

}

class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    ButtonListener() {}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/");

        String J = Bank_Statement.Bank_Statement1();
        driver.findElement(By.id("video")).sendKeys(J + Keys.ENTER);
        driver.findElement(By.id("download")).click();
        String L= driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println(L);

        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd", "/c","start chrome " + L});
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return text.getText();
```

Will be executed right after the Windows appears. It does not wait until the user enters some text.

Try the following:

```
public class Bank_Statement extends JFrame {

    private JTextField text;
    public static Bank_Statement bank_statement;

    public Bank_Statement() {
        //create/set labels
        JButton skinny = new JButton("Convert");
        skinny.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        text = new JTextField("                                                    ");
        JPanel textPane = new JPanel();
        textPane.add(text);

        ...
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public String getText(){
        return text.getText();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        bank_statement = new Bank_Statement();
    }

}

class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    ButtonListener() {}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String J = Bank_Statement.bank_statement.getText();
        System.out.println(J);
    }
}
```

I removed a few lines in the middle to keep it compact. I hope it is clear, ask otherwise. The design is quite bad, but I didn't want to change to mutch of your code.

Comment: So i changed the text variabel to text6 beczuse it seemed to be glitching up

http://prntscr.com/drjflw


Im still getting an error for some reason

Comment: What kind of error? Do you use my Code? It worked for me.

Comment: I appreciate you cleaning up the code haha but you got rid of a lot of important stuff like where it opens up google chrome and the part where it inserts the url in the website online

Comment: You also got rid of the other buttons and textfeilds i was wondering if ther was a way we could keep all of the stuff but fix the errors?

Comment: You can Keep all that stuff, I just wanted to show you, where your mistake was. You cannot return the value of the JTextField. Save the JTextField to class attribute like I did it. Then write a function like I did it, to access that JTextField.

Comment: If you don'T understand I can send you the whole class fixed.

Comment: I uploaded the file [here](https://gist.github.com/GAlexMES/1c3e545d3f3ec163de4c460c99f67fcf)

Comment: "a YouTube to MP3 converter.": do you guys look at this or just blindy answer the question - this is  a fraud obviously

Comment: @gpasch I don't know where you life but in my county it is allowed to download YouTube content for private use.

Answer (score -1):

Well, first of all, I assume this is your constructor for the Bank_Statement class

```
public static String Bank_Statement1() {
    //create/set labels
    JButton skinny = new JButton("Convert");
    skinny.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
    buttonPane.add(skinny);

    JButton skinny2 = new JButton("Paste");
    JPanel buttonPane2 = new JPanel();
    buttonPane2.add(skinny2);

    JTextField text;
    text = new JTextField("                                                    ");
    JPanel textPane = new JPanel();
    textPane.add(text);

    JTextField text2 = new JTextField("----------------------------------------WAIT LIST----------------------------------------");
    JPanel textPane2 = new JPanel();
    textPane2.add(text2);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Youtube Converter");
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.add(textPane, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.add(buttonPane2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.add(textPane2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    return text.getText();
}
```

This is an incorrect use of a constructor.
In this case, your constructor should be declared as:

```
public static Bank_Statement(){
    //constructor code goes here
}
```

then you can declare a getter method for your JTextField value like so:

```
public String getText(){
    return text.getText();
}
```

then you should be able to call that method (getText) in any method once the object is instantiated. Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //just an example...you wouldn't really want to do this
    Bank_Statement recObject = new Bank_Statement();
    recObject.getText();
}
```

But overall this solution is not a "good" fix because there are many other ways to do it that are considered better. This will simply fix your error you are having. I would look into understanding classes and objects better before you continue. :)